# Show input based on other input selection not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
<custom-select label="Target Type" v-model="targetType"
                                            name="targetType" placeholder="Select Target Type"
                                            data-test="overall-type-input" :options="targetTypeOptions"
                                            :value="targetTypeOptions.value" v-validate="'required'" :searchable="false"
                                            :allowEmpty="false">
                                        </custom-select>
                                        <custom-select 
                                             v-if="targetTypeOptions==='OFFER'" v-model="platformValue" label="Offer" v-validate="'required'"
                                            placeholder="Select Offer" data-test="offer-input-options"
                                            name="offer" :options="platformOptions"
                                            :error-messages="errorMessages['offer']" required>
                                        </custom-select>
```

targetTypeOptions is array of objects with label and value

Comment: `:value="targetTypeOptions.value"` when you say "targetTypeOptions is an array of objects". The `:value` should probably be some selected variable `:value="someValue"`

Answer (score 1):

TargetTypeOptions will always have the array of options, :value is used just to set the initial value of the dropdown.

You would need to do,

`v-if = "targetType.value === 'OFFER'"` For this to work!

Comment: Can you tell me if you have any error, or you can add vue devtools, and check the value for targetType. Devtools will help you debug issues like these.

Comment: I actually get undefined for targetType. However I do get the options for the custom select